# Why Spark RDD keeps more number of partitions for small data

Tags: apache-spark

I am creating a RDD by passing a collection to `sparkContext` `parallelize` method. My question is why it gives me 8 partitions as i have only 3 records . Am i getting some empty partitions

```
 scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("surender","raja","kumar"))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:40

scala> rdd.partitions.length
res0: Int = 8

scala> rdd.partitions
res1: Array[org.apache.spark.Partition] = Array(org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@691, 
org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@692, 
org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@693, 
org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@694, 
org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@695, 
org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@696, 
org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@697, 
org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@698)

scala> rdd.getNumPartitions
res2: Int = 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't provide the number of partitions it will create the defined in `spark.default.parallelism` whose value you can check running `sc.defaultParallelism`.

It's value depends on where you are running and on the hardware:

According to the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) (look for `spark.default.parallelism` )

> it depends on the cluster manager:
>   **Local** mode: number of cores on the local machine
>   **Mesos** fine grained mode: 8
>   **Others**: total number of cores on all executor nodes or 2, whichever is larger

You can specify the number of partitions with a second parameter in the `parallelize` method

For instance:

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("surender","raja","kumar"), 5)

scala> rdd.partitions.length
res1: Int = 5

scala> sc.defaultParallelism
res2: Int = 4
```

Comment: Ok. I am not able to see this config in cloudera manager. I checked the cores available in each node of my cluster , it is 32 for nodes and 16 for nodes . I am running a spark-shell from edge node . So where do i see this 8 being set ?

Comment: Did you run sc.defaultParallelism  in your spark-shell?  How many nodes has your edge node?

Comment: sc.defaultParallelism  gives me 8 . My question is what if i want to return  sc.defaultParallelism to 4 or 6 . My edge node has 32 cores